# Setting http://domain and http://ip to show different directories

Tags: ip, virtualhost, httpd, httpd.conf, address

Can someone tell me what httpd.conf settings I need to acomplish this?

When in browser I access http://IP I want to show: /var/www/html/
And when I access http://domain I want to show /var/www/html/_domains/domain

But I don't know how the  (or whatever option) should look like, the http://IP keeps showing the domains directory rather than the html root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ['NameVirtualHost'](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost) on the IP address. Then, for the two individual configurations, use a `VirtualHost` that precisely matches the IP, and a `ServerName` specifying the server's name. For the access by IP address, the server name *is* the IP address.

Comment: I did a `NameVirtualHost IP:port` then two `VirtualHost`; in first the address and ServerName is site.com; and in second, address and ServerName is the IP. It works but I am confused, I was expecting it to work cleaner without specifying exact IP, just by associating a domain to a folder, and all other requests go to document root, without mentioning any IP. Is that possible?

Comment: If you do that, and anything is wrong with DNS when Apache starts up, Apache will [misconfigure itself](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/dns-caveats.html).

Comment: Sorry, you mean it would be bad not to specify IP? Or all setup I mentioned?

Comment: You would be relying on the server to use DNS to find the IP. If that failed for some reason, the server couldn't configure itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using nginx, I would say to have two server blocks, and give the IP-based one an arbitrary name but set the default keyword like so:

`listen 80 default;`